# Use JS/CSS minification tools as python distutils commands?

Tags: javascript, python, css, distutils, minify

I know there are many JS/CSS minification tools out there, but I'm looking for tools that integrate to my python projects as distutils commands, i.e. something I could configure in the `setup.cfg` or `setup.py` file and use with `python setup.py <command>`.

I already found [distwebres](https://github.com/bmathieu33/distwebres) which seems interesting but is not officially published. Are there other tools available?

PS: I am only interested by tools that integrate as regular distutils commands, not buildout recipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote one myself: [Minify](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/minify)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap any command-line tool in a distutils command, actually.  If you’re only interested by tools that integrate as distutils commands because you want them to be written in Python, then you need to use something like distwebres, but if your interest is in having a unified interface (I mean python setup.py command), then any tool can be called by a command.  Depending on the level of configurability you want, it can take ten lines or a hundred.

Comment: My interest is having a unified interface and using aliases to automate many things. I finally wrote a tool that wraps the YUI compressor tool.